# displaying matplotlib plot in djangoview

Tags: django, image, matplotlib

I want to display an image produced by matplotlib in django.
I have a working solution but want to do it without writing to the disk.
Here is the code:

```
def __get_img_data1(): # not working - returns a white blank image
    fig = plt.figure()
    imgdata = StringIO.StringIO()
    fig.savefig(imgdata, format='png')
    imgdata.seek(0)
    content = imgdata.getvalue()
    imgdata.close()
    return content

def __get_img_data2(): # not working - returns a broken image
    fig = plt.figure()
    imgdata = StringIO.StringIO()
    fig.savefig(imgdata, format='png')
    imgdata.seek(0)
    from PIL import Image
    return Image.open(imgdata)

def __get_img_data3(): # working!
    img_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    plt.savefig(img_file.name, dpi=600)
    img_data = open(img_file.name + '.png', 'rb').read()
    os.remove(img_file.name)
    os.remove(img_file.name + '.png')
    return img_data
```

I have taken 3 approaches shown above.
How to make it work without writing to the disk?
It is supposed to work according to the documentation:
http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html

but it displays an empty white image.

Answer (score 0):

uh, I figured out.
The problem is that I needed to get the figure object **before** doing my plotting.

This works:

```
def __get_png_img_buff(fig):
    buff = StringIO.StringIO()
    fig.savefig(buff, format='png')
    buff.seek(0)
    return buff
```